# Diffeomorphism invariance of the Ricci tensor

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It may be a very simple question, but I would be happy to have a quick answer on how we can show that the Ricci tensor is invariant under a diffeomorphism? To be precise, if $ \phi : M\to M$ is a diffeomorphism, I want to show

$$ \text{Ric} (\phi^* g) = \phi^* \text{Ric} (g).$$

Comment: It's *not*. Unless the diffeomorphism is an isometry. All Riemannian manifolds are locally diffeomorphic.

Comment: In the book of Hamilton's Ricci flow, there are several places where it mentioned the diffeomorphism invariance of Ricci tensor. Could you please explain what it means? I guess that  they mean $Ric(\phi^* g)=\phi^* Ric(g)$, where $\phi$ is a diffeomorphism and $g$ is the metric.  My question is that why this holds.

Comment: Strange terminology; I would call it equivariance. I am not prepared to write out the calculation, but does  Hamilton not give a reference for it? What about other books on Ricci flow?

Comment: I found two other posts asking or mentioning somehow similar thing as above http://math.stackexchange.com/q/911717/394544 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661640/ricci-flow-preserves-isometries  any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: I realize now that this is totally standard terminology. It's also immediate if you look at it right. Think of the diffeomorphism as a change of chart. The fact that the Riemann curvature tensor is a tensor tells you that its trace transforms by precisely this rule (think of $\phi^*g$ as the metric in the new chart).

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for your comments. It is now clear to me. I would like to add a reference for anyone that may have the same confusion as me at first. Please see pp 39-40 of the book 'The Ricci flow in Riemannian geometry' by Andrews and Hopper [link](http://rd.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-16286-2).

Answer (score 4):

This question bothered me as well and later I found the solution, so I'm writing it here. It is known from basic Riemannian geometry that curvature is preserved by isometries. So if $\phi : (M,g) \to (\tilde{M}, \tilde{g})$ is an isometry, then $\phi^{*}R(\tilde{g}) = R(g)$.

But in our case, $\phi$ is just a diffeomorphism. But it is an isometry if considered as a map $\phi: (M, \phi^{*}g) \to (M,g)$.

Thus using isometry invariance of curvature we get that

$$
\phi^{*}\text{Ric}(g) = \text{Ric}(\phi^{*}g). 
$$