# Condition for section of the frame bundle of $M$ to be the 1-jet of a local diffeomorphism $\phi: M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism, jet-bundles

We're given an n-dimensional Riemannian manifold $M$ and its frame bundle $FM$. The tangent bundle can be locally regarded as an invertible map $\phi:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let's confine $\phi$ to be $C^{\infty}$.

Choosing some arbitrary section $ \sigma:M\rightarrow FM$ of the frame bundle (and likewise for coframes) we have a set of basis and their dual 1-forms $\left(\sigma_{a},\sigma^{a}\right)$. My question is: when is $\sigma$ the 1-jet $j^{1}\phi$ of $\phi$?

I'm pretty sure the above is enough to say that $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism fixing a point $x\in M$. The question then becomes when is $\sigma$ the 1-jet of a local diffeomorphism on $M$?

Note: In this context our basis can be considered moving frames as in Cartans' *method du repere mobile*

My thought process is as follows:

Let us choose a torsion free connection on $M$ (i.e. $d\sigma^{a}=\omega^{ab}\sigma_{b}$). Now consider the Ricci (curvature) scalar $R$ on $M$. $R$ should be invariant under the map $\phi $ (there is some subtlety here in how you apply $\phi$ discussed for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107935/diffeomorphism-invariance-of-the-ricci-tensor)).

Then I would expect the variation of the curvature with respect to the variation of $\sigma_{a}$ to vanish precisely when our basis are the 1-jets $j^1\phi$.  In other words, the curvature shouldn't change as we vary a diffeomorphism (or Taylor expansions/jets of it) that is when:

$$\delta R/\delta\sigma_{a}=0$$

at every point in $M$. Does this make sense?  If this is off base, what is a sufficient condition?

NOTE:  Any form of Ricci curvature would have sufficed, I only chose the Ricci scalar for it's lack of unmatched indices.

Comment: I do not understand what is written: (1) Given a local diffeomorphism $\phi: M\to R^n$, how does $j^1\phi$ define a section of $FM\to M$? (2) Next, Ricci curvature is not the same as the scalar curvature, you have to decide which one you have in mind. (3) Next, in what sense Ricci (or scalar) curvature supposed to be invariant under $\phi$? Are you assuming that the metric is Ricci-flat or has  zero scalar curvature? I stopped reading after that.

Comment: @MoisheKohan   Re (1) see section 2 of *Moving Frames for Pseudo–Groups.
I. The Maurer–Cartan Forms*  applied to the first order frame bundle only.  Regarding (2), I only mean the *Ricci* scalar not gaussian or any other curvature.   Regarding (3) Ricci curvature is invariant under $\phi$ when regarded as a map $$\phi: (M,\phi^* g) \rightarrow (M,g)$$ (which is discussed in the link in the question)   There are no other assumptions about $M$

Comment: @MoisheKohan   Where $g$ is a metric on $M$

Comment: I have no idea how it addresses my concerns.

Comment: you can find *Moving Frames for Pseudo–Groups. I. The Maurer–Cartan Forms* here, specifically end of page 4, and top of page 5: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=0a67770156975ba0f3ada2f2704e5af9cee2949f

Comment: @MoisheKohan  I believe I addressed all three points in your comment thorougly.

Comment: @MoisheKohan   If you need more, regard $\phi$  as a local chart on $M$, then 1-jets are literally basis on $M$ (i.e. sections of the frame bundle).

Comment: @MoisheKohan  Maybe this helps you: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoordinateChart.html

Comment: I apologize for that, I'm not sure what else i should say...here's another quote: " *The total space $FM$ of the frame bundle of $M$ is an open submanifold of $J^{1} _{n} M$, because $FM$ can be considered as the set of 1-jets at $0\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of local diffeomorphisms of open neighbourhoods of $0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ into $M$.* " -Chapter 1 *Differential Geometry of Frame Bundles*  Cordero, Dodson, and de Leon

Answer (score 1):

Most of what you wrote in the question is either wrong (e.g. the sentence "The tangent bundle can be locally regarded as an invertible map $\phi:\to {\mathbb ℝ}^$" in the opening paragraph) or irrelevant.

Your real question seems to be about finding necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of a local diffeomorphism $M\to {\mathbb R}^n$ with the given "infinitesimal information." In the question you were trying to formulate the problem in terms of sections of the frame bundle, which is unnatural, the natural setting (as we will see below) is that of the **coframe bundle** of $M$. Of course, by introducing a (semi)Riemannian metric on $M$, one gets and isomorphism between the two bundles (and, hence, allows one to restate everything in terms of sections of the frame bundle of $M$), but this only obscures the nature of the problem.

Now, suppose we are given an $n$-dimensional manifold $M$ and a $C^\infty$-map $\phi: M\to {\mathbb R}^n$, $\phi=(\phi_1,...,\phi_n)$, where $\phi_i\in C^\infty(M), i=1,...,n$. This yields an $n$-tuple of differential forms on $M$:
$$
\omega_i=d \phi_i, i=1,...,n.
$$
A map $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism if and only if $\omega_1\wedge ...\wedge \omega_n$ is a **volume form** on $M$ (i.e. a nowhere vanishing $n$-form), if and only if the $n$-tuple
$(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)$ is a section of the **coframe bundle** of $M$.

Conversely, given an $n$-tuple of 1-forms $$(\omega_1,...,\omega_n)$$ on $M$, there exists a smooth map $\phi=(\phi_1,...,\phi_n): M\to {\mathbb R}^n$ with $\omega_i=d\phi_i, i=1,...,n$, if and only if:

(a) Each form $\omega_i$ is closed, $d\omega_i=0, i=1,...,n$. (This condition is sufficient **locally**.)

(b) Each form $\omega_i$ represents zero de Rham cohomology class in $H^1(M; {\mathbb R})$, in other words, each $\omega_i$ is exact. For instance, this condition is automatically satisfied if $H^1(M; {\mathbb R})=0$.

None of this has anything to do with Cartan's method of moving frames, or curvature(s) of some  Riemannian metric on $M$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm having trouble wording my questions appropriately.  Note: you mentioned the intro sentence being wrong. I had thought you could always regard a fiber bundle as a map between the base and fiber at a point, though it's not standard.

Comment: I really only mentioned moving frames as I prefer using them to metrics, since you can use one to construct the dual coframe in leu of the metric. I appreciate your answer. I'll try much harder to formulate my questions appropriately.