# Ricci flow diffeomorphism invariance and evolution of curvature using Uhlenbeck's trick

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

My question, while related to the posts [Ricci flow preserves isometries](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661640/ricci-flow-preserves-isometries), [The invariance of the Ricci tensor under diffeomorphisms and its non-ellipticity.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911717/the-invariance-of-the-ricci-tensor-under-diffeomorphisms-and-its-non-ellipticity), and [Diffeomorphism invariance of the Ricci tensor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2107935/diffeomorphism-invariance-of-the-ricci-tensor), is slightly different. Namely, when using Uhlenbeck's trick in the Ricci flow the Riemann tensor evolves by:

$\frac {\partial } {\partial t} R_{abcd} = \iota_a^i \iota_b^j \iota_c^k \iota_d^l\Delta R_{ijkl} + 2(B_{abcd} - B_{abdc} - B_{adbc} + B_{acbd})$

where $\ B_{abcd} = h^{eg}h^{fi}R_{aebf}R_{cgdi}$ and $\iota : (V,h) \rightarrow (TM,g(t)) $ is a 1-parameter family of isometries from the fixed vector space V with metric h to the evolving tangent space TM with metric g(t) such that $ h=\iota^* g(t)$ for all t.

However, according to the diffeomorphism invariance of the curvature $\iota^* Rm[g(t)]=Rm[\iota^* g(t)] $ and $ h=\iota^* g(t) $ and h is fixed. Shouldn't then

$\frac {\partial } {\partial t} R_{abcd} = \frac {\partial } {\partial t} \iota^* Rm[g(t)]=\frac {\partial } {\partial t}Rm[\iota^* g(t)]=\frac {\partial } {\partial t}Rm[h]=0 ?$

Here $\ Rm[g(t)] $ denotes the Riemann tensor of the metric g(t).

Clearly I am not understanding something correctly. What am I missing?

My reference for this material is:

Andrews, Ben, and Christopher Hopper. The Ricci flow in Riemannian geometry: a complete proof of the differentiable 1/4-pinching sphere theorem. springer, 2010.

Comment: You cite "diffeomorphism invariance", but $\iota$ is an isometry of vector spaces, not a diffeomorphism of manifolds?